# I ended up having unprotected sex with the man I wish to marry, although I didn’t want to

Tags: sex, forgiveness, depression

I ended up having sex with my boyfriend who I plan on marrying, but did not plan on having sex with before marriage. Now that this has happened, I am extremely upset and ashamed of my act aswell. Will God forgive me and help me get rid of this depression? Also, I pray I don't get pregnant. I am extremely depressed with what I have done and I cannot even seek forgiveness for my act seems like the worst I could have done!! Also, I don’t want to get pregnant and I pray to God to protect me and save me from   all this.

Comment: marry him immediately please, so the mistake doesn't repeat

Comment: @Rafid this is not a good nor feasible advice, First both should repent sincerly secondly it is the boy who should marry the girl or ask for her hand in marriage first.

Comment: @ياsr i agree with some of your points

Answer (score 2):

What you did is extremely bad but Allah is a lord that has Mercy on his servant and forgive them, try to pray to Allah and ask for his forgiveness and don't that it as a joke because by Allah what you did is nothing but zinna.
In addition don't leave that your man if possible, marry him as soon as possible so that Allah may have mercy on both of you and forgive him.
But I want you to know that after the praying for forgiveness, both of you should forget about past, leave it for Allah seek and focus on your present and future, I mean don't try it again
Maa Salam